# Routing the right way in .NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm developing an admin panel and I have created a new area called "Admin" to start. Now in my AdminAreaRegistration.cs file the routing is just like this

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     new { controller = "Index", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

So i can reach the admin panel with http://{mydomain}/Admin/

And I have 2 Controllers. 
IndexController to manage the login, signin, etc.
UserController to manage listing users, adding new user, etc.

When i try to access user's list the url will look like that http://{mydomain}/Admin/User/List/ this is pretty good looking url. But when i try to access Signin for a new admin the url will be like this: 
http://{mydomain}/Admin/Index/Signin/

But i didn't like the 2nd url. Can i access the index controller like http://{mydomain}/Admin/Signin/ and the others like first one.

And how would you approach this kind of situation? I really want to do this in right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your Signin url, if you have a Signin Action set-up in your Indexcontroller, set-up a route before your "Admin_default" route like this:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_Signin",
    "Admin/SignIn",
     new { controller = "Index", action = "Signin" }
);
```

You can then link to this action with ActionLinks like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Sign-in here", "Signin", new { controller = "Index", action = "Signin" })
```

Comment: +1 - can you also teach me how to use my new Blue Ray player - I can't be bothered reading the instructions.